# Volley : how can I parse data String with integer by HashMap

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

how can I parse data String with integer by HashMap 
I have String and integer data of json 
and the problem in HashMap he accept just String or integer value
this Is structure of Json

```
   {
   "status":true,
   "message":"Get Products Successfully",
   "products":[
      {
         "p_id":48,
         "p_name":"Ford Red",
         "p_descrption":"rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr",
         "p_price":15000,
         "p_offer_price":12000,
         "p_image":"myLinkimage"
      }
     ]
   }
```

this is my java code

```
 final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "myLink", null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("p_name","mac");
            params.put("p_descrption","mac mac 2018");
            params.put("p_price","10000");
            params.put("p_offer_price","8000");
            params.put("p_image","https://d.top4top.net/p_105212t9r1.jpg");
            return params;
        }
    };


    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

and

```
params.put("p_price","10000");
params.put("p_offer_price","8000");
```

in my json structure it is a integer ,
how can I parse this data like a integer value ?

Comment: `Integer.valueOf` or `Integer.parseInt` maybe? Searching for "Java String to Integer" didn't return any result?

Comment: I don't really see your problem. Maybe it just wasn't explained clearly. Are you having problems parsing the JSON structure at the top of your post?  Or are you having problems with the parameters in `getParams()`? Or is your problem just a simple type conversion as AKSW has pointed out?

Comment: @Barns yes , the problem In parameters , I need set data in hashMap String and integer .

Comment: That should not be an issue. Just convert the `Integer` values to `String` and add them to the `HashMap` in `getParams()`. You are sending the values as parameters to your `POST` request. These parameters will be sent as `String`,  anyway. If needed you can do a type conversion on your webserver.

Comment: You should not be using `getParams` here... That `null` parameter after POST is supposed to be the JSONObject to send to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse anything, rather use JsonObjectRequest as intended.

Which is to move the map from `getParams` method (and possibly remove the method entirely) and then create your payload ahead of the Volley call

```
JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
JSONArray products = new JSONArray();

JSONObject product = new JSONObject();
product.putInt("price", 100);
products.add(product);

payload.putArray("products", products);

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "myLink", payload,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

And if you want to parse *the response*, you can directly call `response.getInt` , for example

If you want, you can combine Volley with Gson, as pointed out in the Android documentation, which makes this implementation cleaner, or Retrofit w/ Gson would work similarly